# how to make a form designer

Tags: html, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

The Problem in Hand: 
I want to make a form designer where user can drag and drop fields of different type and design the layout too, some what similar to [wufoo form builder](http://www.wufoo.com/form-builder/) but here the layout is limited to single column whereas I want to make something where user can make the layout as they want.

I understand how to do in single column view, but could not understand how to achieve multiple column layout eg: row 1 there could be 3 elements, row 2 one element stretched to full length, row 3 there could be just 2 elements etc.

What I tried:
I have tried with jquery UI sortable to make a single column layout with using div where new elements can be dragged and repositioned.

Any suggestion on how to proceed further will be helpful

I have tried searching StackOverFlow and google but could not find any link on a similar topic. If anyone could point me to the same, it will be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you reorder elements on *wufoo form builder*, you can only drag'n'drop up or down. Remove that restriction and as soon as one element is dragged across a certain threshold, it "belongs" to the next column. If the "old" column was the first or last one and the line that the element was moved over was to the "outside" of the form, add a new column there, until the maximal number of columns is reached.

If the used drags the last element of a column into another column, remove the now empty column on element-drop.

You could also remove the dynamic adding/removing of columns and juist have a button ("remove column" & "add column") to do it by code.

An example for the dropping in another column can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Hope this helped!

Edit:
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets and http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists also have elements that you could look into. Good luck! Sounds like a nice project. Can we see any progress or beta?